# Alternatives to joining attributes in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

In QGIS 2.18, I can join attributes stored in a csv-sheet to a shapefile, which works fine. However, when saving the respective layer, the joined attributes are not stored.

Is it possible to add attributes from a separate table permanently to a shapefile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if you have ticked the "Cache join layer in virtual memory" button:

[image: join_attributes]

Comment: I have checked the button. Joining works perfect. I also can store the attributes now, however the culumn naming of the joined attributes changes (which is a minor issue).

Comment: If you don't want a prefix before the column name of your joined attributes, make sure you've ticked Custom name field prefix and leave it blank, as in the above screenshot. Unticking it will result in the default prefix.

Comment: @she_weeds Exactly :)